# HTTP v/s AJP Connectors in Tomcat (In terms of performance) - Tomcat version 9.x

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Scenario: 
I have one java application with Servlet of file uploads.
This application hosted in tomcat 9.0.13 configured behind Apache 2.4 with AJP connector.

In case of larger files upload, I see speed is slow. So I checked in case of Tomcat connector.

1. In AJP connector, **100 MB file upload** takes avg **12-16 Seconds**
2. In HTTP connector, **100 MB file upload** takes avg **4-7 Seconds**

For AJP below lines I have added in Apache conf file

```
<location /filescrum1>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/javascript text/css text/xml application/javascript
    ProxyPass balancer://filescrum1Cluster/filescrum1 timeout=120 stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=Off
</location>

<Proxy balancer://filescrum1Cluster>
    BalancerMember ajp://app11aind2:10003/ route=app11a003 timeout=300 ping=1 retry=120 
    BalancerMember ajp://app11bind2:10003/ route=app11b003 timeout=300 ping=1 retry=120 
</Proxy>
```

And For HTTP connector, below lines I have added in Apache conf file

```
<location /filescrum1>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/javascript text/css text/xml application/javascript
    ProxyPass balancer://filescrum1Cluster/filescrum1 timeout=120 stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=Off
</location>

<Proxy balancer://filescrum1Cluster>
    BalancerMember http://app11aind2:9003/ route=app11a003 timeout=300 ping=1 retry=120 
    BalancerMember http://app11bind2:9003/ route=app11b003 timeout=300 ping=1 retry=120 
</Proxy>
```

There is no changes on code side, and just changing connector cause more then 90% improvements.
I want to know more that this can we tried in production or not? Also HTTP connector is better then AJP or not?

Comment: Versions of everything please - Tomcat, Apache, APR, mod_jk. Do you have other plugins in Apache? What does the rest of the mod_jk config look like? This question cannot be answered in a vacuum.

Comment: If not already configured, please configure an Extended Log Valve with time-taken and come back with the logs, then we are sure of the average times you're mentioning.